# Painting a custom JScrollBar

Tags: java, swing

I want to completely change the look of a scollbar but overriding `JScrollBar` and the `paintComponent` method doesn't work, the track and thumb are painted but the left and right arrows stay the same.
I am also using them inside a JScrollPane and using
`setHorizontalScrollBar( new CustomScrollBar() )` to set the scroll bars to my custom scroll bars but it doesn't work so well, the horizontal scrollbar doesn't change it's orientation, it doesn't change to a vertical scroll bar.

How do I paint a completely new JScrollBar and use it within a `JScrollPane`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a nutshell you need to subclass `ScrollBarUI` with your own implementation and then register it with the `UIManager`.

There's a full article [here](http://explodingpixels.wordpress.com/2008/12/08/skinning-a-scroll-bar-part-1/).

Comment: It looks like a good article but I was hoping for something simpler.
That method actually creates an entirely new scrollbar, it defines completely new functionality.
All I want is to change the look, the rest of the scrollbar must stay exactly the same.

Comment: That article was pretty much useless for me, the code doesn't work by copypasting and i don't know where did WindowUtils came from, i downloaded jna-utils and nothing.