# Swing - Custom scrollbar

Tags: java, swing, scrollbar

I'm currently working on a project on java Swing. I need to make my custom scrollbar. I couldn't find a good tutorial on how to make one. Can anyone help me? Anything will be much apreciated.

Cheers :)
José.

PD: I want the scrollbar to have this looks:

[image]

Comment: search here, questions tagged Q&A with java + swing + JScrollBar

Comment: See ***[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8208508/custom-design-jscollpane-java-swing)*** post.

Comment: Tutorial is here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel
probably synth LookAndFell can make your Job a Little bit easily

Answer (score 0):

This question might be a duplicate from this one :

[Painting a custom JScrollBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290379/painting-a-custom-jscrollbar)

Here is the link given as an answer :

http://explodingpixels.wordpress.com/2008/12/08/skinning-a-scroll-bar-part-1/

Comment: Did it worked? I don't know where is the WindowUtils class, It isn't from jna-utils.